# Why to put * character when you can write code without it

Tags: php, laravel, character

Why do this:

```
Form::label('email', trans('text.email').'*', ['class' => 'col-md-2 control-label'
```

When I can do just this:

```
Form::label('email', trans('text.email'), ['class' => 'col-md-2 control-label'
```

without * in the title in the final website admin version.

Comment: It looks like they're appending it to the `text.email` translation, so the field label will look like `Email *`. Normally when you look at a form label, a `*` is to show the user that the field is required.

Comment: That´s it - I really don´t realize it at the first time, thx.